# How to get id variable into ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

js

```
function SearchInList(_id,_url,_place){
    this.id = _id;
    this.url = _url;
    this.place = _place; /*How to get this value */
};
SearchInList.prototype.FindMe = function (_str){
this.str = _str;
   if (this.str == "") {
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var place = this.place;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("lista-ind").innerHTML = this.responseText;   /*in this place */
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET",this.url+"?id="+this.id,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
   } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("lista-ind").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET",this.url+"?id="+this.id+"&hint="+this.str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
};
```

in HTML I have

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search-ind" ></div>
    <div id="lista-ind" class="lista"></div>
<script>
    var id = <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>;
    var url = "showresults.php";
    var place = "lista-ind";

    var searchInd = new SearchInList(id, url);
    var searchboxInd = document.getElementById("search-ind");

    window.onload = searchboxInd.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
        searchInd.FindMe(searchboxInd.value,place);
        console.log(searchboxInd.value);
    }, false);  

    window.onload = searchInd.FindMe("",place);

</script>
```

and when i have in function in onreadystatechange " document.getElementById("lista-ind")" it is working, but when I change to
 document.getElementById(this.place) it is not.

how to pass this variable into that function?

this is how i made searching in lists.
thanks.
M.

Answer (score 0):

If `place` is a global variable, outside the function, you not need `this`; just the variable name.

```
document.getElementById(place)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating `SearchInList` without a place and `FindMe` does not take place as a parameter, so there is no way to get place to use in the object.
The easiest solution would be to add place as a parameter to `FindMe`

```
SearchInList.prototype.FindMe = function (_str, _place){
  this.str = _str;
  this.place = _place;
  ...
```

Comment: can i have this parameter to SearchInList? 
i have two lists in one page and I need to have two SearchInList objects with different place.

and when i have this.place it is not working.

this function
 function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("lista-ind").innerHTML = this.responseText;   /*in this place */
            }

   doesnt see this.place (but it sees global place)